# How to use QTKit to split a stereo audio track into two mono audio tracks?

Tags: macos, audio, quicktime, qtkit

I've been writing an audio conversion application in OSX meant for use in podcasting, and I've run into an issue. I can access the QTTrack for the audio I want, but it has two very different audio channels on the left speaker and on the right speaker. Is there any way I can create two new audio files and/or play them inside the program - one for the sounds coming from the left speaker, and one for the sounds coming from the right speaker, separately from each other?